# How does the basis of a real space with an almost complex structure induce a basis of the related complex space

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-geometry

If $V$ is a real vector space with an almost complex structure $I$ on $V$ and $(v_1, \dots,v_n)$ is a real basis of $V$, how can I get the induced complex basis of the complex space $(V,I)$?

If I do this the other way around, my idea is that $(w_1,\dots,w_m)$ induce the real basis $(w_1, iw_1, \dots, w_m, iw_m)$. As complex multiplication with $i$ is defined by the almost complex structure $I$ this should be ok to do shouldn't it?

I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Think of $\Bbb R^{2n} \simeq \Bbb C^n$, with $z_j = x_j + i y_j$.

Comment: Then my suggestion would be $(v_1 + I(v_2), \dots, v_{n-1} + I(v_n))$ these are linearly independent because of the fact that real parts and imaginary parts are independent. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a satisfying answer to your question. If you start with a complex basis $w_1, \dotsc, w_m$ and consider $w_1, i w_1, \dotsc, w_m, i w_m$, then in that basis the almost complex structure $I$ has the special form
$$I = \begin{pmatrix}D \\ & \ddots \\ && D,\end{pmatrix} \quad\text{where}\quad D = \begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$
If you just start with an arbitrary $\mathbb R$-basis, this is not the case.

If you start with a real basis $v_1, \dotsc, v_n$ such that $I$ has this form, you can simply take every second basis vector $v_1, v_3, \dotsc, v_{n-1}$ to obtain a complex basis with the correct property.

Comment: For the converse, one first need to start with a real basis in which $I$ has this form. As you notice, general bases lead nowhere

Comment: @Didier In that case, just take every second basis vector.